# OpenStreetMap: get coordinates from address

Tags: geolocation

Is there any function in OpenStreetMap that gives you the coordinated from an address ?

something like

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/locate?request=GetGeocoding&nbaddresses=1&outputFormat=json&addresses_0=1240+Place+Jourdan+PARIS
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I have it, Nominatim is a tool to search OSM data by name and address and to generate synthetic addresses of OSM points (reverse geocoding).

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=135+pilkington+avenue,+birmingham&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1

Comment: for reverse geocoding the url is: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=[value]&lon=[value]&[params]  
The entire api is here https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Overview/

Comment: how to change response language?

Comment: @roghayehhosseini Did you find a solution to search for addresses located in Iran via OSM?

Comment: It's not accurate, I don't recommend using this

Comment: do you recommend better tools @EhsanA.Kian ?

Comment: I think Google Maps API is the best option.